# why banner ads appear in dev mode but not in the publish app?

Tags: react-native, expo, banner-ads

i had create an android mobile application with react native and expo framework. i did the code to add a banner ads in the home component of my application. i used react-native-google-mobile-ads package.
when i'm in development mode the banner appear correctly in my emulator but when i publish my application on google play store and i download my app on my smartphone, the banner don't appear. Please, someone know why ?

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Pressable, Modal, TextInput, StyleSheet, View, Text, Button, Share, Alert } from 'react-native';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import i18n from '../i18n.js';
import mobileAds, { AdsConsent, AdsConsentStatus, BannerAd, TestIds, BannerAdSize } from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';
import { firestore } from '../FirebaseConfig.js';
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import * as Network from 'expo-network';

function Home() {
    //define variables and state
    const adUnitId = __DEV__ ? TestIds.BANNER : "ca-app-pub-7771306695979114/8272761826";
    const [location, setLocation] = React.useState(null);
    const [errorMSG, setErrorMSG] = React.useState(null);
    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(true);
    const [name, setName] = React.useState("");
    const [firstname, setFirstname] = React.useState("");
    const [consent, setConsent] = React.useState(null);
    const consentInfo = React.useRef();
    const formAvailable = React.useRef();
    const status = React.useRef();
    const [docId, setDocId] = useState(null);
    let latitude = null;
    let longitude = null;
    let altitude = null;


    useEffect(() => {
        const docIds = async () => {
          try {
            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('docId');
            if (value !== null) {
              // value previously store
              setDocId(value);

            } else {
              console.log('they is not doc id for now');
            }
          } catch (e) {
            // error reading value
            console.error(e);
          }
        };
        docIds();
        //function to clear the async storage. uncomment if you need it
        //AsyncStorage.clear();
        //AdsConsent.reset();
        }, []);

    //function to add consent status
    async function addUsersConsentInfos() {
       formAvailable.current = await consentInfo.current.isConsentFormAvailable;
       status.current = await consentInfo.current.status;
    };

    //function to add users consent
    async function adsUserConsent() {

      //request user info status
      consentInfo.current = await AdsConsent.requestInfoUpdate();
      addUsersConsentInfos();

      if (consentInfo.current.isConsentFormAvailable !== undefined && consentInfo.current.status !== undefined) {

        if (consentInfo.current.isConsentFormAvailable && consentInfo.current.status === AdsConsentStatus.REQUIRED) {

          const formResult = await AdsConsent.showForm();

        }

        const {storeAndAccessInformationOnDevice} = await AdsConsent.getUserChoices();


          //verify the store and acces device info status (true or false)
        if (storeAndAccessInformationOnDevice === false) {

              setConsent(false);
                /**
                * The user declined consent for purpose 1,
                * the Google Mobile Ads SDK won't serve ads.
                */

        } else if (storeAndAccessInformationOnDevice === true) {

            //modify consent variable state
            setConsent(true);

            //initialize the ad load
            await mobileAds()
            .setRequestConfiguration({
            // Indicates that you want your content treated as child-directed for purposes of COPPA.
              tagForChildDirectedTreatment: true,

              // Indicates that you want the ad request to be handled in a
              // manner suitable for users under the age of consent.
              tagForUnderAgeOfConsent: true,

            })
            //initialize the mobile ads
            mobileAds().initialize();

        } else if (storeAndAccessInformationOnDevice === undefined ) {
              console.log('store access status is undefined');
        } else if (storeAndAccessInformationOnDevice === null) {
              console.log('store access status is null');
        } else {
              console.log('on ne sait pas');
        }

      } else {
          console.log('consent info undefined');
          const formResult = await AdsConsent.showForm();
      };
    };
    //call the adsUserConsent function
    adsUserConsent();

return (
              <View style={styles.container}>
                  { docId === null ?
                  <Modal
                     animationType="slide"
                     visible={modalVisible}
                  >
                     <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder={i18n('name')} onChangeText={setName} value={name}/>
                     <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder={i18n('firstname')} onChangeText={setFirstname} value={firstname}/>
                     <Pressable style={styles.submit} onPress={onPress}>
                        <Text style={styles.textPressable}>{i18n('validate')}</Text>
                     </Pressable>
                  </Modal>
                  : null
                  }
                  <Button title={i18n('addPosition')} onPress={getUserLocation}/>
                  <Text style={styles.text}>{text}</Text>
                  <Button title={i18n('sharePosition')} onPress={sharePosition}/>
                  <Text>{"\n\n\n\n"}</Text>
                  { consent === true ?
                  <BannerAd
                    unitId={adUnitId}
                    size={BannerAdSize.ANCHORED_ADAPTIVE_BANNER}
                  />
                  : null }
              </View>
           )
};

export default Home;
```

i have a dev web site with app-ads.txt. my app is ready and approuve by google mobile ads and google play store. all the annexe file like app.json was correctly configure as you can see next :

app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "owner": "mg_production",
    "name": "my position",
    "slug": "my-position",
    "version": "1.0.7",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/ic_launcher.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/ic_launcher.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/ic_launcher.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.mg_production.myposition",
      "versionCode": 8
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/ic_launcher.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-localization",
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "extraProguardRules": "-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.consent_sdk.** { *; }"
          }
        }
      ]
    ],
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "c7ead926-a6f3-4db9-80ef-3596f30d421c"
      }
    }
  },
  "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-7771306695979114~3792830459",
    "delay_app_measurement_init": true
  }
}
```